# Disable swapfile encryption on Maverics

Tags: macos

does anyone know how to disable the default encryption of the swap file ?

i tried this by setting the default preferences

```
$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.virtualMemory DisableEncryptedSwap -boolean yes
```

but this doesn't work :(

```
$ sysctl vm.swapusage
vm.swapusage: total = 1024.00M  used = 0.00M  free = 1024.00M  (encrypted)
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The option to disable the encryption was removed in recent versions of [dynamic_pager](https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-670.1.2/dynamic_pager.tproj/dynamic_pager.c.auto.html).

Answer (score 0):

OS X Mavericks uses [dynamic_pager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/dynamic_pager.8.html) to manage the swap file. The key name is `UseEncryptedSwap` not DisableEncryptedSwap.

So try

```
$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.virtualMemory UseEncryptedSwap -boolean NO
```

Comment: nop... swap file is still encrypted after boot. i guess there must be an new key or preset somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [dynamic_pager.c](https://github.com/st3fan/osx-10.9/blob/34e34a6a539b5a822cda4074e56a7ced9b57da71/system_cmds-597.1.1/dynamic_pager.tproj/dynamic_pager.c) (source code of dynamic_pager) the key is called **DisableEncryptedSwap** and has to be located inside **/Library/Preferences/com.apple.virtualMemory.plist**.

I tried this with 10.9.5:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.virtualMemory DisableEncryptedSwap -boolean YES
```

After reboot `sysctl vm.swapusage` shows no longer any encryption.

Comment: Unfortunately today (still at 10.9.5 and with all Security patches applied) this tip doesn't work. After reboot, `sysctl vm.swapusage` still shows "(encrypted)" even after deleting **/var/vm/swapfile** prior to rebooting... Please can you confirm on your Mac and revert to us?